# An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue

Tags: json

I am trying to upgrade the redmine. In order to create the session variable, after following several steps I have to run the bundle install to make sure all the gems are instaalled

```
 Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension
 C:/PROGRA~1/BITNAM~1/ruby/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make
gcc -I. -I/C/PROGRA~1/BITNAM~1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32 -I/C/PROGRA~1/BITN
AM~1/ruby/lib/ruby/1.8/i386-mingw32 -I. -DJSON_GENERATOR    -g -O3 -DFD_SETSIZE=
256   -Wall -O0 -ggdb  -c generator.c
/bin/sh: /usr/mingw/bin/gcc: Bad file number
make: *** [generator.o] Error 126

    enter code here

Gem files will remain installed in C:/PROGRA~1/BITNAM~1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/g
ems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/PROGRA~1/BITNAM~1/ruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/json-1.8.1/ex
t/json/ext/generator/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I am not able run the command bundle install in ruby

Comment: Were you able to solve the problem?

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by running `bundle update json` before `bundle install`.

Answer (score 2):

```
bundle update json
```

Did not work for me,

Instead i did run following command.

```
bundle update
```

and then

```
bundle install
```

---

I am running a Kali, was trying to install SNORBY after successful installation of SNORT, PULLED PORK and BARNYARD2.
Above solution fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try locking JSON gem to 1.8.0 in your gemfile and doing an update

```
gem 'json', '1.8.0'
```

then run

```
bundle update json
```

Comment: I found I only needed the `bundle update json` to make this work. `bundle` itself it wanted to install json 1.7.6, but the update installed a later version that worked.